# How to show Chinese characters in Floating Terminal inside Neovim?

Tags: neovim, encoding

As title. Also I'm using Neovim inside Tmux. I've tried both with/without Tmux and the results are the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will be a popular and helpful question, since I cannot find any related websites after Googled "nvim floating term Chinese" and similars. Just add the following:

```
export LANG=zh_TW.UTF-8          # or en_US.UTF-8 as indicated in the Ref. below
```

I put an issue there: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/16400

Comment: In general, yes, you need the locale settings to use the right encoding and language